# PHP Imagick outline/contour and sketch

Tags: php, image-processing, imagick, contour, outline

I have a problem with getting fine **contour of the image**.

**How to do it with PHP Imagick?**

Input image: *Imagick wizard*

### Plan #1 Outline

1. Get image with (more/less) clear, consistent background (for example: white, red or transparent)
2. Remove background if it is set
3. Add outline (specific color)
4. Remove image inside

Result: http://i57.tinypic.com/2wg91qx.png

### Plan #2 Sketch

1. Get image with (more/less) clear, consistent background (for example: white, red or transparent)
2. Remove background if it is set
3. Add sketch effect
4. Remove image inside

Result: http://i60.tinypic.com/az9vr5.png

---

PS:
borders and/or shadows didnt' work for me well

Comment: I got stuck trying add outline. Don't know how to  
contour/fringe the real image... I've tried to add shadow - unsuccessfully

Comment: see my answer on exactly how to resolve this problem using ImageMagick command line utilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945964/create-contour-with-php?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to outline a picture. Here's one of them that does more or less what you wanted. Note that wizard's picture requires some extra processing. First background isn't fully white (it has some #FEFEFE or alike pixels). Also what is more troubling the upper part of the desk is filled with pure white. So you can either use white pixels after blurring as background (my way) or try to flood fill from the corner with `matteFloodfillImage()`. However this may leave space between desk legs not transparent.

```
function drawImage(Imagick $i) 
{
    $i->setImageFormat("png");
    header("Content-Type: image/" . $i->getImageFormat());
    echo $i;
    exit;
}

$o = new Imagick('wizard.png');
$o->setImageBackgroundColor('white'); // handle tranparent images
$o = $o->flattenImages(); // flatten after setting background
$o->blurImage(5, 30);
$o->whiteThresholdImage( "#F8F8F8" );
$o->blackThresholdImage( "#FFFFFF" );
$o->edgeImage(5);
$o->negateImage(false);
$o->paintTransparentImage($o->getImagePixelColor(0, 0), 0, 2000);
$o->colorizeImage("red", 1);

drawImage($o);
```

Sketching is a little more complex and I would recommend further reading on IM capabilities http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#color-in

Comment: Great answer! But could you tell me why it isn't working with .png files with transparent background? The same image as .jpg works well :O (in comparison to the .png file)

Comment: I think ```edge``` requires solid background. See the updated code - it should handle both transparent and not transparent images