# Create contour with PHP

Tags: image-processing, contour

I am working on a project that requires creating an outer contour from a bitmap image. eg. please check the images below.  Is there any php library that I can use to achieve this task? I have found open source library http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html but this is not on php

> bitmap image only

[image: bitmap image only]

> bitmap with contour

[image: bitmap with outer contour]

Thanks for any clues.

Comment: You could try imagemagick:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057570/solved-php-imagick-outline-contour-and-sketch.

Comment: @Betterdev, I am not looking for 'Sketching' and it does not help me. What I am trying to achieve is an 'outer contour'. please look at the above images.

Comment: @Laxman have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with imagemagick. Although there's a PHP API for ImageMagick, I think it's much easier and safer to just  spawn/execute asynchronously the convert command and read the output images from FS

[Working online demo](https://cancerberosgx.github.io/demos/magica/playground/#state=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)

I took that from [this discussion](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=31654&sid=485d2bc58c62e24244c65ad897c74350)